PHP Shopify Graph API. Error syntax error, unexpected invalid token ("\"") at [33, 2]
I use cURL, not a github library.
I have a next code
$query = <<<GRAPHQL
        mutation InventorySet(\$input: [InventorySetQuantitiesInput!]!)
        { 
            inventorySetQuantities(input: \$input) {
                inventoryAdjustmentGroup {
                    createdAt
                    reason
                    changes {
                        name
                        delta
                    }
                }
                userErrors {
                    field
                    message
                }
            }
       }";
       GRAPHQL;

        $variables = [
          'input' => [
              'name' => 'available',
              'quantities' => [
                'inventoryItemId' => $inventoryItemId,
                  'locationId' => $locationId,
                  'quantity' => $newQuantity
              ],
              'reason' => 'correction'
          ]
        ];
        return $this->makeGraphQLRequest($query, $variables);

why do i get the error
syntax error, unexpected invalid token ("\"") at [33, 2]
Please help
Explanation of the error and what to fix in the code

There is one single location in that code that contains a double quote, }";.

Please replace your query with this and in the variable you need to add one more key "compareQuantity" and its value will be the existing product have the available quantity like: 0, 1, 2 etc.
        mutation InventorySet($input: InventorySetQuantitiesInput!) {
          inventorySetQuantities(input: $input) {
            inventoryAdjustmentGroup {
              createdAt
              reason      
              changes {
                name
                delta
              }
            }
            userErrors {
              field
              message
            }
          }
        }

$variables = [
          'input' => [
              'name' => 'available',
              'quantities' => [
                'inventoryItemId' => $inventoryItemId,
                  'locationId' => $locationId,
                  'quantity' => $newQuantity,
                  'compareQuantity'=> 1
              ],
              'reason' => 'correction'
          ]
        ];

